# How to secure PHP Services that are using in HYBRID Mobile App?? Explain in Clearly.I am new to PHP.Simply I created Services Like

Tags: php

How to secure PHP Services that are using in HYBRID Mobile App?? Explain in Briefly.I am new to PHP, I just want to learn how to create secured services in 
PHP and want to use them in Mobile App.Simply I created Services Like Below

```
<?php 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type:Application/Json',false);
    include("functions.php");
    if(!empty($_GET['view']))
    {
        $view = $_GET['view'];
        $employees = getDetails();
        if(empty($employees))
        {
            deliver_response(200,"data not found",NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            deliver_response(200,"data found",$employees);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        deliver_response(400,"invalid request",NULL);
    }
    function deliver_response($status,$status_message,$data)
    {
            header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");

            $response['status']=$status;
            $response['status_message']=$status_message;
            $response['data']=$data;
            if($status_message=="data found")
        {
                $json_response=json_encode($data);
        }
        else
        {
            $json_response=json_encode($response);

        }
        echo $json_response;
    }
?>
```